# "ReplaceWith" & - but only part of it

Tags: python, regex, match

I need to perform a search/replace on text which contains a comma which is NOT followed by a space, to change to a comma+space.

So I can find this using:

```
,[^\s]
```

But I am struggling with the replacement; I can't just use:

```
 , (space, comma)
```

Or

```
& ,
```

As the match originally matches two characters.

Is there a way of saying '&' - 1 ? or '&[0]' or something which means; 'The Matched String, but only part of it' in the replacement argument ?

Another way of trying to ask this:

1. Can I use Regex to IDENTIFY one part of my string.
2. But REPLACE a (slightly different,but related) part of my string.

I could just probably replace every comma with a comma+space, but this is a little more controlled and less likely to make a change I do not need....

For example:

Original:

```
Hello,World.
```

Should become:

```
Hello, World.
```

But:

`Hello, World`.

Should remain as :

```
Hello, World.
```

And currently, using my (bad) pattern I have:

Original:

```
Hello,World
```

After (wrong):

```
Hello, orld
```

I'm actually using Python's (2.6) 're' module for this as it happens.

Comment: please give your regex pattern too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using parantheses to capture a part of the string is one way to do it. Another possibility is to use "lookahead assertion":

```
,(?=\S)
```

This pattern matches a comma *only if* it is followed by a non-whitespace character. It does not match anything followed by comma but uses that information to decide whether or not to match the comma.

For example:

```
>>> re.sub(r",(?=\S)", ", ", "Hello,World! Hello, World!")
'Hello, World! Hello, World!'
```

Comment: Thanks for this - gave this the accepted answer as the additional explanation of why this mechanism works was very much appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use parentheses to "capture" part of the string that matches your expression.  I'm not up to speed on Python's implementation, but it should give you some kind of array called match[] whose elements correspond to the captures.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could. But why would you, in this simple case?

```
def insertspaceaftercomma(s):
    """inserts a space after every comma, then remove doubled whitespace after comma (if any)"""
    return s.replace(",",", ").replace(",  ",", ")
```

seems to work:

```
>>> insertspaceaftercomma("Hello, World")
'Hello, World'
>>> insertspaceaftercomma("Hello,World")
'Hello, World'
>>>
```

Comment: Yup, agreed - for this simple case, but of course my actual problem involved more than this. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

You can look for a comma + non-space character and then stick a space in between them:

```
re.sub(r',([^\s])', r', \1', string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re

s1 = 'Hello,World.'
re.sub(r',([^\s])', ', \g<1>', s1)
> Hello, World.

s2 = 'Hello, World.'
re.sub(r',([^\s])', ', \g<1>', s2)
> Hello, World.
```